# Re-arrange UILabel after new line

Tags: swift, view, label

I have a label which gets its text from textfield and has a limit in width of imageview where it is on. I want to add a new line when the limit has reached. However, i couldn't do it with "\n" and wordwrapping function. In addition, i need to set UILabel's height and width to exactly texts size. I mean if it has two lines height should for two line only not much and exact same for the width property.

```
func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
   if(imageview.frame.width > label.frame.width + 2)
   {
    label_test.text = "\(label.frame.width)"
     label.text = textfield.text
        if(imageview.frame.width < label.frame.width + 20)
        {
            label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
            label.text = textfield.text! + "\n"
            label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center;
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use lineBreakMode ? In my opinion you should define a basic setup in your viewDidLoad or so :

```
func viewDidLoad() {
  //Your stuff
  label.frame.size.width = imageview.frame.width //Define max width
  label.numberOfLines = 0 //Set infinite number of lines
  label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
}
```

Then in your textfieldShouldEndEditing you set the text and the height

```
label.text = textfield.text
label.sizeToFit() //The height is adjusted
```

Comment: Because the label is draggable inside the imageview if i do it like that the label won't be draggable because it is frame limits are already be equal to imageviews frame values.